# JS Regex string don't end up with a period/dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to have a validation for a particular string but it can't end up with a period/dot, how could you achieve that?

Valid string:

- .string
- ._string
- string
- stri.ng
- st_ring
- st._ring
- st_ri_ng

Invalid string:

- string.
- _string.
- stri.ng.
- st_ring.
- st._ring.
- st_ri_ng.

Comment: Put it at the end (?! \.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is `/[^.]$/`.

However, I must ask: does it need to be regex? If not, you can just read the last character and compare it to `"."`.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be Regex for the front end username validation! By the way with your Regex it only matches last character, I would like to match all characters ```[a-z0-9_.]``` as long as period not in the end.

Comment: My pattern is meant to be tested against the string. If you need it for the entire string parsing (with assumed ^ and $), go with `[\w.]*\w`

Comment: For curiosity how would you allow any character in the string to match as long at it doesn't end up with a period?

Comment: Just like I did in the original answer. There is an exclusion operator in regex, which applies for a group in square brackets. `[^.]` means "anything but the period".

Comment: Yes, it looks cool. Keep in mind though that usually you can skip the `^.*` part.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Live saver!

Comment: If an empty string is to be matched (it does not have a period at the end) use `(?<!\.)$` instead.

Comment: You usually want to assume non-empty string in regex rules. Just like for the numeric regex, for example, you'd put `^\d+$` and not `^\d*$`. We use patterns as "what should it be" and in OP's case, it's supposed to be an alphanumeric string with possible dots, but not ending with a dot. Empty string is not that.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much simpler to use the [`endsWith`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_endswith.asp) method:

```
var validString = '.string';
var invalidString = 'string.';

validString.endsWith('.'); //false
invalidString.endsWith('.'); //true
```

Comment: Instead of keeping the check in regex, it also makes sense to check it directly too like your answer. Thanks for the tip.